# Extract separte values from url query string parameter

Tags: query-string, url-parameters, querystringparameter

I've gotten soooo lost on the approach. I'm using a tag manager to fire a custom script that extracts the full query string from a url...bare in mind, I deploy analytics tracking and am not a developer at all.

This works already to get the query string parameters

**var queryString = decodeURIComponent(location.search.split("&").join(":")).substring(1);
return queryString;**

Started to see urls with
**"?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=local&utm_content=editorial"** coming through...

Would anyone be able to help me build on the code from above to extract only 1 value?

sorry for reaching out if it's been done, our implementation is bad for analytics so until we use proper campaign tracking, separating these are what I have to figure out :( #havemercy

thanks x300, seriously

Answer (score 0):

Google will provide many solutions for this, but here's another quick ES5 example:

```
function getQueryParams() {
    var queryStringItems = decodeURIComponent(location.search).substring(1).split('&');
    var queryParams = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < queryStringItems.length; i++) {
        var component = queryStringItems[i];
        var keyValue = component.split('=');
        queryParams[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
    }
    return queryParams;
}
```

Usage for printing the value for query parameter `myQueryParam` to the console would be the following:

```
var queryParams = getQueryParams();
console.log(queryParam['myQueryParam']);
```